# SQL Server SSRS query Issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following query:

```
SELECT        
    pupils.txtSchoolID, pupils.txtPreName, pupils.txtSurname,
    pupils.txtForm, pupils.txtAdditionalHealth, pupils.txtAllergyNotes,
    notes.txtNote
FROM 
    TblPupilManagementPupils AS pupils 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TblPupilManagementHealthNotes AS notes ON pupils.txtSchoolID = notes.txtSchoolID
```

I need to only pull the `notes.txtNote` when `notes.txtType = 'Dietary'`, however, when I set this in a `WHERE` clause, I only get entries with Type Dietary, I still need all of the pupil's table data also. I thought the left outer join would do this.

When setting the `WHERE` clause, I try

```
WHERE notes.txtType = 'Dietary'
```

but this also does not work, I have been setting as a parameter temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove where clause and put that condition on clause because

Logically, all JOINs are performed as INNER JOINs using the ON filters, and then, as a subsequent step, any OUTER JOIN rows are added back to the necessary side. After all JOINs are complete is the WHERE filter processed. as a result when you applied it on where it removed all expect `Dietary` values records

```
SELECT        pupils.txtSchoolID, pupils.txtPreName, pupils.txtSurname,
pupils.txtForm, pupils.txtAdditionalHealth, pupils.txtAllergyNotes,
notes.txtNote

FROM TblPupilManagementPupils AS pupils LEFT OUTER JOIN
TblPupilManagementHealthNotes AS notes
ON pupils.txtSchoolID = notes.txtSchoolID and notes.txtType = 'Dietary'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go! Sometimes miss the little things! Seems logical, thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition (`notes.txtType = 'Dietary'`) with `ON` clause :

```
. . . 
FROM TblPupilManagementPupils AS pupils LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TblPupilManagementHealthNotes AS notes 
     ON pupils.txtSchoolID = notes.txtSchoolID AND notes.txtType = 'Dietary';
```

If you filter the `LEFT OUTER JOINED`  table data with `WHERE` clause, then you are making a join as `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and reply.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively less optimized route is; run your query as is with no where clause and no additional on clause. Insert data into temp table and then filter that data as so; where notes.txtType = @Param . and this @Param you declare topside for stored procedure or query as @Param varchar(200) to capture whatever expected front end value your expecting.